# How much fluid friction occurs on the side of a boat?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

There is the overall drag (bow, stern, sides). That is fairly complicated to calculate. What about only the sides of a long boat with parallel sides.

Comment: Even this restricted problem is pretty difficult if you admit wave-making drag as well as viscous drag (which you must with surface vessel that you want to have going at even modest speeds).

Comment: @dmckee how about we only look at viscous drag.

Comment: If you want only an estimate you can calculate drag on a flat plate.